# python async - functions not starting at the same time

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have the following program here

```
`
import datetime
import asyncio
import time
import math

async def count1():
    s = 0
    print('start time count 1: ' +str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    for i in range(100000000):
        s += math.cos(i)
    print('end time count 1: ' +str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    return s

async def count2():
    s = 0
    print('start time count 2: ' +str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    for i in range(1000000):
        s += math.cos(i)
    print('end time count 2: ' +str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    return s

async def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    task = asyncio.gather(count1(), count2())
    results = await task
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Result 1: {results[0]}")
    print(f"Result 2: {results[1]}")
    print(f"Total time taken: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is

```
start time count 1: 2023-02-16 12:26:19.322523
end time count 1: 2023-02-16 12:26:40.866866
start time count 2: 2023-02-16 12:26:40.868166
end time count 2: 2023-02-16 12:26:41.055005
Result 1: 1.534369444774577
Result 2: -0.28870546796843
Total time taken: 21.73 seconds
```

I am trying to get count1() and count2() to start working at the same time, as it seen it the output it's not happening. count2() only starts after count1() has ended, and I am not sure why.

I also tried replacing the lines in main() with:

```
task1 = asyncio.create_task(count1())
task2 = asyncio.create_task(count2())
result1 = await task1
result2 = await task2
```

not also does not result in count1() and count2() starting at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`async` is essentially [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). Neither function `await`s, so they hog the entire process for as long as they run and don't yield to other functions.

You could add a strategic

```
if i % 10000 == 0:
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

in the loop so they "give way" to other async coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Async doesn’t mean “running at the same time”. Async means that when one of the functions waits (typically for some I/O), the control can be passed to another function.

In practice async can be used e.g. to have one process wait for several responses from web at the same time. It won’t allow you to e.g. run the same computation on several CPU cores (this stuff is generally hard to achieve in Python due to the infamous GIL problem).